# Derive evolution equation for scaling function from Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X_t\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a $n$-dimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process with:
\begin{equation}
dX_t = A X_t dt + B dW_t,
\end{equation}
where $A$ has negative eigenvalues and $B$ is positive-definite and $W_t$ is a standard $n-$dimensional Wiener process.

We denote by $\nu(x)$ its invariant measure and define the associated infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{A}$:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{A} \psi(x) =  \langle Ax, \nabla \psi \rangle + tr(Q \nabla^2 \psi),
\end{equation}
where $Q = \frac{1}{2}B B^\top$.

The pdf of $X_t$ denoted $\pi(x,t)$ follows the Fokker-Planck equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \pi(x,t)}{\partial t} = \mathcal{A}^\star \pi(x,t),\; \pi(x,0) = \pi_0(x)
\end{equation}

where $\mathcal{A}^\star$ is the adjoint of the operator $\mathcal{A}$ given by:

\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{A}^\star p(x,t) = - \nabla(A x\;  p(x,t)) + tr(Q \nabla^2 p(x,t))
\end{equation}

In  Stochastic Processes and Applications Diffusion Processes, the Fokker-Planck and Langevin Equations (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-1323-7) eq. (4.44) p.104, they show that $\pi(x,t)$ can be written as $\pi(x,t) = h(x,t) \nu(x)$, where $h(x,t)$ is the solution of the backward Kolmogorov equation:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial h(x,t)}{\partial t} = \mathcal{A} h(x,t), h(x,0) = \pi_0(x)/\nu(x)
\end{equation}

I am facing some challenges to derive this equation:

My idea was to plug the product $h(x,t) \nu(x)$ in the Fokker-Planck equation and use that $\frac{\partial \nu(x)}{\partial t} = \mathcal{A}^\star \nu(x) = 0$, but I don't know how to cancel certain terms:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \pi(x,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial h(x,t)}{\partial t} \nu(x) = -\partial_{i}((Ax)_i h)\nu(x) + h(x,t) \{ -\partial_{i}((Ax)_i \nu(x)) + Q_{ij} \partial^2_{ij} \nu(x))\} + Q_{ij} \partial^2_{ij} h \nu(x) + Q_{ij} \partial_i h \; \partial_j \nu(x) + Q_{ij} \partial_j h \; \partial_i \nu(x),
\end{equation}

where the term in curly bracket equates to zero from $\mathcal{A}^\star \nu = 0$. By symmetry of $Q$, one can regroup the last two terms.

I have so far:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial h(x,t)}{\partial t} = & -\partial_{i}((Ax)_i h) + Q_{ij} \partial^2_{ij} h  + 2Q_{ij} \partial_i h \; \partial_j \log \nu(x)\\
 = & - tr(A) h(x,t) - \langle A x, \nabla h \rangle + Q_{ij} \partial^2_{ij} h  +
 2Q_{ij} \partial_i h  \partial_j\log\nu(x)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I would sincerely appreciate your help in this derivation.